# Evaluate a string as an formula in Excel without VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to evaluate a formula from a string (Excel). The string is been take it via VLOOKUP() function.
I have an table with formulas "Formulas". Via an drop down cell I like to select what Formula I like to apply.
This is one of the strings: `"pi()*(B5+2*C5/1000)"`
I have trying the following extra function to complete this task without success:

```
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(A38;formulas;2;))
=INDIRECT("="&"pi()*(B5+2*C5/1000)")
=TEXT(INDIRECT("="&"pi()*(B5+2*C5/1000)");)
=INDIRECT(TEXT(INDIRECT("="&"pi()*(B5+2*C5/1000)");))
```

So in cell A38 I have an drop down menu:
-Function1, Functin2, Function3 etc....

I am not interested in an VBA solution. Maybe exist something without VBA.

Thank you!

Comment: Why no VBA? That *is* the way to do this, and it's very easy.

Comment: From the top op my head, I don't think `INDIRECT` would evaluate through VBA.

Comment: I know it is easy with VBA but I have to do it without VBA (if it is possible).

Comment: See second answer for non vba method.

Comment: Be aware that the solution provided won't always recalculate.  You can also refer to https://superuser.com/questions/253353/excel-function-that-evaluates-a-string-as-if-it-were-a-formula/1385388#1385388